# How to store structs (not instance) that implement a common trait?

Tags: rust

## Background

I have a trait `MyTrait`:

```rust
trait MyTrait {
    fn name() -> String;

    fn foo();
}
```

`name` defines its name, and `foo` is its [associated function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions), which does some work for me.

## Target

I have many structs that implements this trait, and I want to define a function

```rust
fn do_work(name: &String);
```

which finds the struct `TheStruct` where `TheStruct::name()` is `name`, and call `TheStruct::foo()`.

## Problem

To achieve my goal, I need a `HashMap` or use `match`, but the target value should be a struct (not instance) implements `MyTrait`, but this seems impossible.

## Workaround

Change `name()` and `foo()` to struct methods, i.e. `name(&self)` and `foo(&self)`, then use `HashMap` or just `match` to get the things right. But I think since `name()` and `foo()` does not need an instance by design, why should I need to instantiate it?

Comment: If the hashmap is mapping a type name to a function, could you make it a `HashMap<String, fn()>` so it is the responsibility of the function that inserts items into the map to look up the function off the trait, so `do_work` wouldn't need to know about `MyTrait` at all?

Comment: @loganfsmyth This works. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mapping a name to an action, it would make the most sense to use a `HashMap<String, fn()>` most likely. For example:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, hash_map::Entry};

trait MyTrait {
    fn name() -> String;

    fn foo();
}

struct Example;
impl MyTrait for Example {
    fn name() -> String { 
        "Example".to_string() 
    }
    fn foo() { 
        println!("Do Example"); 
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Worker {
    handlers: HashMap<String, fn()>,
}
impl Worker {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Default::default()
    }
    fn register_handler<T: MyTrait>(&mut self) {
        let name = T::name();
        match self.handlers.entry(name) {
            Entry::Occupied(_) => panic!("handler already registered"),
            entry => {entry.or_insert(T::foo);},
        }
    }
    fn do_work(&self, name: &str) {
        let handler = self.handlers.get(name).expect("unknown handler");
        handler();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut worker = Worker::new();
    worker.register_handler::<Example>();

    worker.do_work("Example");
}
```

([Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5c064f3db3f36d7059655b47b4f521c0))